# Python pandas to_csv zip format

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I am having a peculiar problem when writing zip files through to_csv.

**Using GZIP:**

```
df.to_csv(path_or_buf = 'sample.csv.gz', compression="gzip", index = None, sep = ",", header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

gives a neat gzip file with name '**sample.csv.gz**' and inside it I get my csv '**sample.csv**'

However, **things change when using ZIP**

```
df.to_csv(path_or_buf = 'sample.csv.zip', compression="zip", index = None, sep = ",", header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

gives a zip file with name '**sample.csv.zip**', but **inside it the csv has been renamed to 'sample.csv.zip' as well**.
Removing the extra '.zip' from the file gives the csv back.

How can I implement zip extension without this issue?
I need to have zip files as a requirement that I can't bypass.
I am using python 2.7 on windows 10 machine.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Please refer to this [discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11413)

Answer (score 28):

It is pretty straightforward in pandas since version 1.0.0 using dict as compression options:

```
filename = 'sample'
compression_options = dict(method='zip', archive_name=f'{filename}.csv')
df.to_csv(f'{filename}.zip', compression=compression_options, ...)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: if anyone is still listening here.. where can I find all the possible compression options? ie. all the dictionary key names i can use over and above 'method', 'archive_name' ones..

Comment: Quote from this the pandas the link I posted: "If compression mode is ‘infer’ and path_or_buf is path-like, then detect compression mode from the following extensions: ‘.gz’, ‘.bz2’, ‘.zip’ or ‘.xz’. (otherwise no compression). If dict given and mode is one of {‘zip’, ‘gzip’, ‘bz2’}, or inferred as one of the above, other entries passed as additional compression options."

Comment: i'm likely not asking clearly.. i get all that.. but when it says 'additional compression options' i want to know all the options. from the example i know there are the 'method' and 'archive_name' options.. but what is the full list of options available to pass to the compression engine?  for instance, in unix commandline for zip, the -j option would mean 'do not include the full path in the compressed file'.. but what would the member name be in the compression_options for the equivalent to "-j"?

Comment: @daBich - I had the same question. I dug into the Pandas code, and with the exception of the key "method", all other items in the compression options dict are passed through as **kwargs to the appropriate Python compression constructors.  So since gzip.GzipFile accepts compresslevel as an argument, it would be valid to pass {"method":"gzip", "compresslevel":9} as compression options. The standard Python compression libs are used, so look up docs for gzip.GzipFile, bz2.BZ2File, and zipfile.ZipFile, to see what arguments they take. Relevant source code in pandas/io/common.py in get_handle()

Comment: Thanks @sql_knievel ! did you happen to stumble upon the -j equivalent argument specifically? That would be worthy of an Answer if so..

Comment: @daBich Let's take this conversation back to your original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029435/accessing-zip-compression-options-in-pandas-to-csv/69227345#69227345

Answer (score 5):

Since Pandas 1.0.0 it's possible to set compression using `to_csv()`.

Example in one line:

```
df.to_csv('sample.zip', compression={'method': 'zip', 'archive_name': 'sample.csv'})
```

Answer (score 3):

As the [thread](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11413) linked in the comment discusses, ZIP's directory-like nature makes it hard to do what you want without making a lot of assumptions or complicating the arguments for `to_csv`

If your goal is to write the data directly to a ZIP file, that's [harder than you'd think](http://swl10.blogspot.com/2012/12/writing-stream-to-zipfile-in-python.html).

If you can bear temporarily writing your data to the filesystem, you can use Python's `zipfile` module to put that file in a ZIP with the name you preferred, and then delete the file.

```py
import zipfile
import os

df.to_csv('sample.csv',index=None,sep=",",header=True,encoding='utf-8-sig')

with zipfile.ZipFile('sample.zip', 'w') as zf:
    zf.write('sample.csv')
os.remove('sample.csv')
```