# Accessing zip compression options in pandas to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zip, export-to-csv

I am having trouble finding the compression options available to me..
At the bottom of this page:
[to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)
they have an example that shows 2 options:

> compression_opts = dict(method='zip',
> archive_name='out.csv')

But I see no listing of all options available.. and can't find one elsewhere.
I'd love to see the full list (assuming there are more than these 2)

End goal currently: the zip operation zips the file up in a zip file, but all the folders are also within the zip file, so that the file is actually buried in a bunch of folders within the zip. I'm sure there is an easy option to prevent the folders from being added to the zip...

Comment: seems the unix commandline option would be -j ...

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand your question.  Let's say I have a dataframe, and I want to save it locally in a zipfile.  And let's say I want that zipfile saved at the location `somepath/myfile.zip`

Let's say I run this program (also assuming that `somepath/` is a valid folder in the current working directory):

```
### with_path.py

import pandas as pd

filename = "myfile"
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 1], ["b", 2]])

compression_options = {"method": "zip"}
df.to_csv(f"somepath/{filename}.zip", compression=compression_options)
```

If I list the content of the resulting file, I can see the path I wanted to store the zip file at was ALSO used as the name of the file INSIDE the zip, including the folder structure, and still named .zip even, which is weird:

```
(.venv) pandas_test % unzip -l somepath/myfile.zip
     
Archive:  somepath/myfile.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       17  09-17-2021 12:56   somepath/myfile.zip
---------                     -------
       17                     1 file
```

Instead, I can supply an `archive_name` as a compression option to explicitly provide a name for my file *inside* the zip.  Like so:

```
### without_path.py

import pandas as pd

filename = "myfile"
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 1], ["b", 2]])

compression_options = {"method": "zip", "archive_name": f"{filename}.csv"}
df.to_csv(f"somepath/{filename}.zip", compression=compression_options)
```

Now although our resulting zip file was still written at the desired location of `somepath/` the file *inside* the zip does NOT include the path as part of the filename, and is correctly named with a .csv extension.

```
(.venv) pandas_test % unzip -l somepath/myfile.zip

Archive:  somepath/myfile.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       17  09-17-2021 12:59   myfile.csv
---------                     -------
       17                     1 file
```

The strange default behavior doesn't seem to be called out in the documentation, but you can see the use of the `archive_name` parameter in the final example of the [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) documentation.  IMHO they should throw an error and force you to provide an `archive_name` value, because I can't imagine when you would want to name the file inside a zip the exact same as the zip file itself.

Comment: This is getting close! Problem is that i don't always know the extensions of the files. they may not always be 'csv'.   I haven't noticed the files inside the zip having a zip extension. I've just had the issue with the full path being used.  Do you see the zip extension even when there are many files being zipped?   Does it appear when you actually unzip rather than using the -l ?   Would still be best if there was a parameter that directly corresponds with the -j option.

Comment: i wonder if junk_paths : true or something similar would work..  i might give that a try when i have a few moments

Comment: @daBich Can you describe your use case a bit more? If you're specifically exporting files from Pandas (as the link in your original question suggests) then you should be able to determine the correct extension from your export logic.  (How would you know the extension if you were writing it to disk not inside a zip?)  If you're not using Pandas at all and just zipping up random files together, or manipulating a zip file that already exists, then you probably want to use the Python zipfile module directly: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 1):

After some reseach about `to_csv`'s integrated the compression mechanisms, I would suggest a different appoach for your problem:

Assuming that you have a number of DataFrames that you want to write to your zip file as individual csv files (for this example I keep the DataFrames in a list, so I can loop over them):

```
df_list = []
df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 2, 3],
                             'col2':['A', 'B', 'C']}))
df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4, 5, 6],
                             'col2':['a', 'b', 'c']}))
```

Then you can convert each of these DataFrames to a csv string in memory (not a file) and write that string to your zip archive as a file (e.g. `df0.csv`, `df1.csv`, ...):

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file="out.zip", mode="w") as zf:
    for index, df in enumerate(df_list):
        csv_str = df.to_csv(index=False)
        zf.writestr("{}{}.csv".format("df", index), csv_str)
```

**EDIT:**

Here is what I think pandas does with the compression options (you can look at the code in [Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) or in your local filesystem among the python libraries):

When the `save` function in `pandas/io/formats/csvs.py` is called, it will use `get_handle` from `pandas/io/common.py` with the compression options as a parameter. There, *method* is expected as the first entry. For *zip*, it will use a class named `_BytesZipFile` (derived from `zipfile.ZipFile`) with the *handle* (file path or buffer), *mode* and *archive_name*, which explains the example from the pandas documentation. Other parameters in `**kwargs` will just be passed through to the `__init__` function of the super class (except for *compression*, which is set to `ZIP_DEFLATED`).

So it seems that you can pass ***allowZip64***, ***compresslevel*** (python 3.7 and above), and ***strict_timestamps*** (python 3.8 and above) as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile), which I could verify at least for *allowZip64* with python 3.6.

I do not see a way to use something like the `-j` / `--junk-paths` option in the `zipfile` library.

Comment: Sorry.. like didn't ask clearly.. but yes, i know that those options are under the 'method' member of the dict to pass to pandas.. and i also know the  'archive_name' member of the dict.  But i only know those member names thanks to the example in that pandas doc.   I do not know what other member names are available.   The question you link to is quite long about using zipfile to handle folders. While that is all good, my main question is how to translate the available features, into member names in the dict for pandas.

Comment: A general listing of the dict member names somewhere would be great, but the immediate need is the option to NOT include the full path within the zipped file. Even a way to translate zipfile options to dict member names.. if that is what pandas is doing..

Comment: @daBich: OK, I hope I now got what your problem is... rewrote my answer.

Comment: so you don't think other options are available through pandas?   what would zipfile's equivalent be to the unix -j option for zip? (ie. don't include the full path within the zip)

Comment: I have added what I think pandas does with the compression options, but unfortunately I do not see an equivalent to the -j option.