# Pandas - Compress Multiple data frames to a single zip folder

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I am using pandas to compress single data frame and save into a compressed folder.

```
compression_opts = dict(method='zip',archive_name=file_name+'.csv')
raw_hs.to_csv('/home/codespace/final_file.zip', index=False,compression=compression_opts)#raw_data = pd.read_csv('Hunting Sellers.csv')
```

I have also tried using zipfile package but it could not help as it creates a multiple folders inside the compressed folder

```
import zipfile
file_1_path = r'folder1/folder2/file_1.csv'
file_2_path = r'folder1/folder2/file_2.csv'
file_3_path = r'folder1/folder2/file_3.csv'
file_4_path = r'folder1/folder2/file_4.csv'


lista_files = [file_1_path,file_2_path,file_3_path,file_4_path]
with zipfile.ZipFile('out.zip', 'w') as zipMe:        
    for file in lista_files:
        zipMe.write(file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Is there any way that I could extract and compress the multiple dataframe into a single compressed folder via pandas ??

Comment: does the top answer not answer your question from here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754165/python-pandas-create-zip-file-from-csv` You can try:  `raw_hs.to_csv('my_file.gz', index=False, compression='gzip')` EDIT, I do not think you can qrite to a `zip` file using this method, only `gzip`. Please see the comment `"Right now we can read .zip but not write .zip files, any plans to include write to .zip?"` from https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11413

Comment: Something is wrong with wither `file_name` or your path in `to_csv`. For a `.zip` file, this seems like the best answer in 2020 and worked for me. No need to use the `zipfile` library -- you can do this with straight `pandas`. I have just confirmed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62006252/6366770

Comment: file_name is good checked and updated all my codes but nothing is working as I expect