# When using pandas dataframe.to_csv(), with compression='zip', it creates a zip file with two archive files with the EXACT same name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, duplicates, zip

I am trying to save OHLCV (stock pricing) data from a dataframe into a single zipped csv file as follows. My test data is [ohlcvData.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rc3ff8jkj7wyx5p/ohlcvData.csv?dl=1), which I read into a dataframe with

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ohlcvData.csv', header=None, names=['datetime', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], index_col='datetime')
```

and when I try to write it to a zip file like so (following [stackoverflow.com/questions/55134716](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134716/python-pandas-to-csv-zip-format)) :

```
df.to_csv('ohlcvData.zip', header=False, compression=dict(method='zip', archive_name='ohlcv.csv'))
```

I get the following warning ...

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\zipfile.py:1473: UserWarning: Duplicate name: 'ohlcv.csv'
return self._open_to_write(zinfo, force_zip64=force_zip64)*

and the resultant ohlcvData.zip file contains two files, both named ohlcv.csv, each containing a portion of the results.

When I try to read the zip file back into a dataframe ...

```
dfRead = pd.read_csv(ohlcvData.zip', header=None, names=['datetime', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], index_col='datetime')
```

... I get the following error...

```
 *File "C:\Users\jeffm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 618, in get_handle
    "Multiple files found in ZIP file. "
ValueError: Multiple files found in ZIP file. Only one file per ZIP: ['ohlcv.csv', 'ohlcv.csv']*
```

However, when I reduce the number of rows in the input file from 200 to around 175 (for this file structure it varies slightly how many lines I have to remove depending on the data), it works and produces a zip file,  containing one csv file, which can be loaded back into a dataframe without error. I have tried many different files, with different data and formats and I still get the same result -- any file with over (approx) 175 lines fails and any file with less works fine. So it looks like its splitting the file after a certain size, but from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) there doesn't appear to be such a setting. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug introduced in 1.2.0, I created a minimal reproducing example and posted an issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39190

```py
import pandas as pd

# enough data to cause chunking into multiple files
n_data = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': ["Raphael"]*n_data,
    'mask': ["red"]*n_data,
    'weapon': ["sai"]*n_data,
    }
)

compression_opts = dict(method='zip', archive_name='out.csv')
df.to_csv('out.csv.zip', index=False, compression=compression_opts)

# reading back the data produces an error
r_df = pd.read_csv("out.csv.zip")

# passing in compression_opts doesn't work either
r_df = pd.read_csv("out.csv.zip", compression=compression_opts)
```

Comment: Thanks. Good to know, so until they fix it I guess I'll just write the csv file first, zip it with ZipFile and remove it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this may be a recent Pandas bug.  I was having the same issue in Pandas 1.2.0.  Reverting to 1.1.3 (i.e. what I was using before) solved the issue.  I haven't tested 1.1.4 and 1.1.5.